# Thank you Cloud Page performance

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

We have a Thank You cloud page that updates several data extensions with ampscript upon submission of a first cloud page. We see a bit of a delay when showing the html because of this code. Is there a way to show first the html and then execute the ampscript in the background? I was thinking of another Cloud Page where I host all the code being called from my Thank You page. Not sure if Redirect ampscript or even an Ajax call can help here.

The code looks something like this

```
%%[

SET @subscriber_key = RequestParameter("subscriber_key")
SET @email = RequestParameter("email_address")
...
  
     SET @rowsupdated  = upsertData("LOG_DE",2,"subscriber_key", @subscriber_key, "email", @email, ...)
     SET @rowsupdated  = upsertData("LOG_DE2",2,"subscriber_key", @subscriber_key, "email", @email, ...)
     SET @rowsupdated  = upsertData("LOG_DE3",2,"subscriber_key", @subscriber_key, "email", @email, ...)


]%%

<!DOCTYPE html>


  <head>


  </head>
    
<body>
        
                  
                    
    <div>
       <br /> Thank you for your submission <br />

    </div>
               
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share your code so that we can better understand what you’re doing

Comment: @zuzannamj right I have updated the question

Comment: I doubt simple data upsert functions would cause a big delay.. can you check in the Console > Network tab which elements are taking the longest to load? I just run a quick test on one of my AMPscript forms and all functions run post-submission took around 0.6 seconds

Comment: Oh I see we load 2 css libraries and that's probably no needed. Thanks @zuzannamj, feel free to answer and I will mark it.